# Generating Word Documents with content contorls

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have an word document template that only changes in several fields.

I remember looking around using google-fu and found that you can bind an xml to content controls and dynamically generate word documents through that method.

Unfortunately it's been a while since I revisited this particular problem, and all I remember about this problem was that it was unnessarily clunky and hard to manage.

Are there any opensource solutions that are more elegant? Or a better way to go at this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fair to describe content control XML data binding as the latest in a series of techniques which enable Word document generation/automation.

Content control data binding was introduced in Word 2007, so is now not all that new.  When you do document automation, you generally also want support for:

- conditional inclusion/exclusion of content
- repeating data (eg table rows, list items)

There are ways to do both of the above with content controls, and Microsoft has recently released dedicated support for repeating data.

Content control data binding is less brittle than older approaches, but if you don't like XML and XPath, you might not call it elegant :-)

The legacy approaches "baked-in" to Word include:

- fields: MERGEFIELD, form fields, or custom fields
- use of bookmarks

A problem with these is that it is easy for the author user to mistakenly delete them.  Another problem is that they aren't as easy for a developer to work with at the XML level (though maybe OK via VBA or VSTO).

The other approach is to include magic text strings on the document surface, and there are various tools around which do this.  This has an initial appeal, but the problem with this is that what looks like a contiguous text string on the document surface can be split up at the XML level, because of:

- spelling/grammar correction
- rsid (edits made at different times or by different people)
- formatting (eg font size, appearance changes)

In short, yeah, there are alternatives.  Choose your poison.